# c++ STL set difference

Tags: c++, stl, set, stdset, set-difference

Does the C++ STL set data structure have a set difference operator?

Answer (score 165):

Yes there is, it is in `<algorithm>` and is called: [`std::set_difference`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference). The usage is:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <set>
#include <iterator>
// ...
std::set<int> s1, s2;
// Fill in s1 and s2 with values
std::set<int> result;
std::set_difference(s1.begin(), s1.end(), s2.begin(), s2.end(),
    std::inserter(result, result.end()));
```

In the end, the set `result` will contain the `s1-s2`.

Comment: +1. 
Sadly, when I needed that, I gave up and rolled my own loop :(

Comment: BTW, if you use set_difference on a non-associative container class, say a vector, make sure the elements in both containers are sorted first...

Comment: #include <algorithms> -> No such file, should be <algorithm> ?

Comment: for set<string> I had to qualify std::insert_iterator< set<string >>(...)

Comment: @stefanB: first comment is correct, and as to the second one: common is to use `std::inserter` instead. No qualification is needed since this is a function.

Comment: The docs say `set_difference` requires both containers to be sorted. Is `set` really sorted? It is not obvious.

Comment: @Ayrat Of course std::set is sorted. For set_difference to work, you must make sure that the set and set_difference use the same comparison.

Comment: with C++20 you could use the ranges variant 


`#include <algorithm>
#include <set>
#include <iterator>
// ...
std::set<int> s1, s2;
// Fill in s1 and s2 with values
std::set<int> result;
std::ranges::set_difference(s1, s2, std::inserter(result, result.end()));`

Comment: What is the most efficient way of doing this when you want the result to be stored in `s1` rather than a new set (`result`)? In other words, the desired behavior is `s1 = s1 - s2`.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, there is a [set_difference](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/set_difference.html) function in the algorithms header.

**Edits:**

FYI, the set data structure is able to efficiently use that algorithm, as stated in its [documentation](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/set.html).  The algorithm also works not just on sets but on any pair of iterators over sorted collections.

As others have mentioned, this is an external algorithm, not a method.  Presumably that's fine for your application.

Comment: It's usable on _any_ pair of sorted containers.

Answer (score 5):

Once again, boost to the rescue:

```
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <boost/range/algorithm/set_algorithm.hpp>

std::set<std::string> set0, set1, setDifference;
boost::set_difference(set0, set1, std::inserter(setDifference, setDifference.begin());
```

setDifference will contain set0-set1.

Answer (score 4):

Not an "operator" in the language sense, but there is the set_difference algorithm in the standard library:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_difference.html

Of course, the other basic set operations are present too - (union etc), as suggested by the "See also" section at the end of the linked article.

Answer (score 2):

The chosen answer is correct, but has some syntax errors.

Instead of

```
#include <algorithms>
```

use

```
#include <algorithm>
```

Instead of

```
std::insert_iterator(result, result.end()));
```

use

```
std::insert_iterator<set<int> >(result, result.end()));
```

Comment: or just use `std::inserter(result, result.end())`

Answer (score 2):

C++ does not define a set difference operator but you can define your own (using code given in other responses):

```
template<class T>
set<T> operator -(set<T> reference, set<T> items_to_remove)
{
    set<T> result;
    std::set_difference(
        reference.begin(), reference.end(),
        items_to_remove.begin(), items_to_remove.end(),
        std::inserter(result, result.end()));
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not as a method but there's the external algorithm function set_difference

```
template <class InputIterator1, class InputIterator2, class OutputIterator>
OutputIterator set_difference(InputIterator1 first1, InputIterator1 last1,
                              InputIterator2 first2, InputIterator2 last2,
                              OutputIterator result);
```

http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/set_difference.html

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, it does.

[SGI - set_difference](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/set_difference.html)

Answer (score 1):

All of the answers I see here are O(n). Wouldn't this be better?:

```cpp
template <class Key, class Compare, class Allocator>   
std::set<Key, Compare, Allocator> 
set_subtract(std::set<Key, Compare, Allocator>&& lhs,
             const std::set<Key, Compare, Allocator>& rhs) {
    if (lhs.empty()) { return lhs; }
    // First narrow down the overlapping range:
    const auto rhsbeg = rhs.lower_bound(*lhs.begin());
    const auto rhsend = rhs.upper_bound(*lhs.rbegin());
    for (auto i = rhsbeg; i != rhsend; ++i) {
        lhs.erase(*i);
    }
    return std::move(lhs);
}
```

That seems to do the right thing. I'm not sure how to deal with the case that `Compare`'s type doesn't fully specify its behavior, as in if `Compare` is a `std::function<bool(int,int)>`, but aside from that, this seems to work right and should be like O((num overlapping) • log(`lhs.size()`)).

In the case that `lhs` doesn't contain `*i`, it's probably possible to optimize further by doing an O(log(`rhs.size()`)) search for the next element of `rhs` that's >= the next element of `lhs`. That would optimize the case that `lhs = {0, 1000}` and `rhs = {1, 2, ..., 999}` to do the subtraction in log time.

Answer (score -1):

can we just use

```
 set_difference(set1.begin(), set1.end(), set2.begin(). set2,end(),std::back_inserter(result)).
```

Comment: `std::back_inserter` requires the `push_back()` method on the target container `result`. This will not work if `result` is a `std::set`

Comment: Please do not put questions in answers.