# Set difference in C++

Tags: c++, set, intersection

If I know that one set is a subset of another set and I would like to find the difference, what's the most efficient way to do this?

ex.
PSEUDO CODE

```
> set<int> set1 = {1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10}
> set<int> set2 = {5 6 7}
```

I want to subtract `set2` from `set1`:

The answer here would be

```
{1 2 3 4 8 9 10}
```

Comment: what would you like? difference or intersection? make your mind up! ;)

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_difference/

Comment: possible duplicate of [c++ STL set difference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/283977/c-stl-set-difference)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use `std::set_difference` found in `<algorithm>`:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <set>
#include <iterator>
// ...
std::set<int> s1, s2;
// Fill in s1 and s2 with values
std::set<int> result;
std::set_difference(s1.begin(), s1.end(), s2.begin(), s2.end(),
    std::inserter(result, result.end()));
```

[Snippet source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283977/c-stl-set-difference)

Comment: How do you know this works? It is not infers from documentation, stating elements should be sorted.

Comment: @Dims std::set is always sorted.

Answer (score 12):

I would use [`std::set_difference`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_difference/), which runs in *O(n)* time.

Comment: `which runs in O(n) time` depends on implementation.

Comment: @nightcracker: nope, it's guaranteed by the standard.

Comment: @nightcracker: see The ISO C++ standard section [alg.set.operations].

Comment: @ybungalobill: Ah found it, §25.4.5.4
set_difference, Remark 4: "At most 2 * ((last1 - first1) + (last2 - first2)) - 1 comparisons." Indeed, `O(n)`.

Comment: @nightcracker: actually you're partially right. The standard doesn't talk in terms of O-notation because, e.g., each insertion or comparison may run in non-bounded f(n) time. So even with linear number of comparisons it may take more than O(n) time.

Comment: ybungalobill: Not true. One operation is one comparison. Whether or not that comparison is O(1) is a completely different story.