# Extract difference of `std::set` containers with lambda function

Tags: lambda, stl, set, c++17, set-difference

I'd like to extract the differences between two sets.
[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703111/set-difference-in-c) provides an adequate answer when I need the result in another container as well.

The following code demonstrates what I'd like to do:

```cpp
std::set<std::string> s1, s2, difference;
std::string difference_string = "";
std::set_difference(
  s1.begin(), s1.end(), s2.begin(), s2.end(),
  std::inserter(difference, difference.end()));

for (const std::string& s: difference) {
  difference_string += s + ",";
}
if (0 < duplicateInPorts.size()) {
  difference_string.pop_back(); //remove last comma
}
```

except I find it inconvenient to create a local variable, when in essence I'd like to have a string only about the contents; Which I could easily compile with a lambda.

Is there a convenience function in `std` which would enable me to do that?
What I had in mind has similar syntay as `std::transform`.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a convinience function in `std`, but there is one in `boost`.

[The example](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/iterator/doc/html/iterator/specialized/function_output.html) for `boost::function_output_iterator` is almost exactly what you want. Slightly adapted:

```
struct string_joiner
{
    string_joiner(std::string& s)
        : m_str(s)
    {}

    void operator()(const std::string& x) const
    {
        m_str += m_sep;
        m_str += x;
        m_sep = ",";
    }

    std::string& m_str;
    std::string mutable m_sep;
};

int main(int, char*[])
{
  std::set<std::string> s1, s2;
  std::string difference = "";

  std::set_difference(
    s1.begin(), s1.end(),
    s2.begin(), s2.end(),
    boost::make_function_output_iterator(string_joiner(difference)));

  std::cout << difference << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

And `function_output_iterator` is just a wrapper around a callable that gives it the interface of an iterator. `operator*` returns a proxy who's `operator=` calls the function.

Comment: shouldn't `std::inserter` work with a string by the way?

Comment: @DávidTóth no, that can only insert individual `char`s or `std::initializer_list<char>`. It will call [`std::string::insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/insert) with an iterator and a value.

Comment: actually not even initializer_list, `std::insert_iterator` only operates on references to the [container's `value_type`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/insert_iterator/operator%3D)