# Does boost have a datatype for set operations that is simpler than the STL?

Tags: c++, boost, stl, set

I find [the C++ STL method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/284004/794283) of doing simple set operations quite clunky to use. For example, to find the difference between two sets:

```
std::set<int> newUserIds;
set_difference(currentUserIds.begin(), currentUserIds.end(), mPreviousUserIds.begin(), mPreviousUserIds.end(), std::inserter(newUserIds, newUserIds.end()));
std::set<int> missingUserIds;
set_difference(mPreviousUserIds.begin(), mPreviousUserIds.end(), currentUserIds.begin(), currentUserIds.end(), std::inserter(missingUserIds, missingUserIds.end()));
mPreviousUserIds = currentUserIds;
```

Does boost offer an alternative set of classes that would reduce the above example to something like this:

```
set_type<int> newUserIds = currentUserIds.difference(mPreviousUserIds);
set_type<int> missingUserIds = mPreviousUserIds.difference(currentUserIds);
```

(Similar to [QSet](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qset.html) in Qt which overrides `operator-` in this way.)

Comment: It's a five-finger exercise to write that if you want it.

Comment: It is but it leaves me with a personal base of code to import into any project where I need it, which isn't always possible (e.g. at work) and makes it harder for others to understand the code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See [Boost Range Set algorithms](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/algorithms/set.html). They still expect an output iterator though.

Answer (score 93):

Nope.  But I here is how to clean it up.

First, rewrite iterator based functions as ranged based functions.  This halves your boilerplate.

Second, have them return container builders rather than take insert iterators: this gives you efficient assignment syntax.

Third, and probably too far, write them as named operators.

The final result is you get:

```
set<int> s = a *intersect* b;
set<int> s2 = c -difference- s;
set<int> s3 = a *_union_* (b *intersect* s -difference- s2);
```

... after writing a boatload of boilerplate code elsewhere.

As far as I know, boost does step 1.

But each of the above three stages should reduce your boilerplate significantly.

Container builder:

```
template<typename Functor>
struct container_builder {
  Functor f;
  template<typename Container, typename=typename std::enable_if<back_insertable<Container>::value>::type>
  operator Container() const {
    Container retval;
    using std::back_inserter;
    f( back_inserter(retval) );
    return retval;
  }
  container_builder(Functor const& f_):f(f_) {}
};
```

which requires writing `is_back_insertable` (pretty standard SFINAE).

You wrap your ranged based (or iterator based) functor that takes a back_insert_iterator as the last argument, and use `std::bind` to bind the input parameters leaving the last one free.  Then pass that to `container_builder`, and return it.

`container_builder` can then be implicitly cast to any container that accepts `std::back_inserter` (or has its own ADL `back_inserter`), and `move` semantics on every `std` container makes the construct-then-return quite efficient.

Here is my dozen line named operator library:

```
namespace named_operator {
  template<class D>struct make_operator{make_operator(){}};

  template<class T, char, class O> struct half_apply { T&& lhs; };

  template<class Lhs, class Op>
  half_apply<Lhs, '*', Op> operator*( Lhs&& lhs, make_operator<Op> ) {
    return {std::forward<Lhs>(lhs)};
  }

  template<class Lhs, class Op, class Rhs>
  auto operator*( half_apply<Lhs, '*', Op>&& lhs, Rhs&& rhs )
  -> decltype( named_invoke( std::forward<Lhs>(lhs.lhs), Op{}, std::forward<Rhs>(rhs) ) )
  {
    return named_invoke( std::forward<Lhs>(lhs.lhs), Op{}, std::forward<Rhs>(rhs) );
  }
}
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dfbdf7cdde234414) using it to implement `vector *concat* vector`.  It only supports one operator, but extending it is easy.  For serious use, I'd advise having a `times` function that by default calls `invoke` for `*blah*`, an `add` for `+blah+` that does the same, etc.  `<blah>` can directly call `invoke`.

Then the client programmer can overload an operator-specific overload and it works, or the general `invoke`.

[Here is a similar library being used to implement `*then*`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27068396/c11-pattern-for-factory-function-returning-tuple) on both tuple-returning functions and futures.

Here is a primitive `*in*`:

```
namespace my_op {
  struct in_t:named_operator::make_operator<in_t>{};
  in_t in;

  template<class E, class C>
  bool named_invoke( E const& e, in_t, C const& container ) {
    using std::begin; using std::end;
    return std::find( begin(container), end(container), e ) != end(container);
  }
}
using my_op::in;
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/42e907eada8e8b94).

Comment: Whoa. Named operators. Mind. blown. Why have I never thought of this before?

Comment: What the...? Now that is an interresting thing (even if more from a theoretical point of view, I guess, but who knows).

Comment: @KonradRudolph Here, have an [implementation](http://liveworkspace.org/code/12lxjX$40).  `make_infix<'*'>(arbitrary_binary_functor)` returns a named operator on `*`.  (everything below `make_infix` is various kinds of test code)

Comment: @Yakk The implementation was easy once you named the concept. … although I think I’d use `<op>` or `%op%` (the latter because it’s the syntax R uses).

Comment: Well... thank you for this. Not quite what I had in mind (!) but an interesting insight into what's possible in deep C++.

Comment: @KonradRudolph the precedence of a named operator in C++ is the same as the "surrounding" operators.  `%op%` thus ties with other multiplication/division operators in precedence, and `<op>` is looser than anything except assignment, logical, and `==` type operations.  `v1 *dot* v2 + v3` follows expected precedence rules, as does `v0 *dot* v1 <cmp> v2 *dot* v3`.  Given that any binary operator works, and it has meaning, I simply let the user choose -- so `make_infix<'%','<>'>(func)` gives you your syntax.  A nice side effect is `vec1 +append= vec2;` syntax reads real pretty as well.

Comment: @Yakk Yes, I noticed that. See the (very brief) discussion in [my question on Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/23179/308).

Comment: Can you make an isolated example (one file only) that implements an `in` operator?

Comment: @noɥʇʎԀʎzɐɹƆ  added to answer

Comment: You need to forward-declare `named_invoke`.

Comment: @noɥʇʎԀʎzɐɹƆ I provided code that compiles on both gcc and clang that does not in the live example link.  Why do you think forward declaration is required?  ADL covers a multitude of sins.

Comment: @noɥʇʎԀʎzɐɹƆ Get a better static code analyzer.  Or just write `template<class...Ts>void named_invoke(Ts&&...)=delete;` in the named operator namespace before use, which could shut it up.  Might not; is really working around a bug in the analyzer, so who knows what I need to do.

Comment: @noɥʇʎԀʎzɐɹƆ It just does whatever the code you put into the `named_invoke` does.  In this case, I wrote a linear find.  You can write overloads, fancy SFINAE based code, or whatever in it.  You can make the container be a binary tree, a linear array, a sorted array, a hash table, or a myriad of other options.  The performance is ... whatever you write.

Comment: @noɥʇʎԀʎzɐɹƆ There is no reason for there to be any overhead after inlining over a "direct" call to `named_apply`, except maybe blocking an elision and replacing it with a `move` if your `named_apply` takes by value.  Everything else is expression templates, fancy, but there isn't a reason for them to actually exist at runtime.

Comment: @Yakk But statistics speak louder

Comment: @noɥʇʎԀʎzɐɹƆ [Look 10^18 iterations in zero time](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3bc042c3d3b5ed00).  If you want help profiling something that compiles away to nothing, ask a SO question about it.  There is nothing to profile, the named operator code doesn't exist in the output of an optimizing compiler.  I'm sure there are compilers that fail to optimize it or cases where it cannot be done, but that is a quality of implementation issue in that particular compiler.

Comment: OK, but noop doesn't really count, does it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133669/discussion-between-nohtyyzar-and-yakk).

Answer (score 3):

No and I think it never have something like that, this is a general principle in C++ that when you can have a non-member function to do the job never make that function a member. so it can't be like that, but may be [Boost::Range](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/) help you.

Comment: I think OP’s beef wasn’t with the nonmember functions – the member function implementation was just an example. And there are trivial (and not so trivial) ways of making OP’s code way more concise with a proper library without having to use member function (Boost.Range does offer such a way, I believe).