# A min= idiom in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading, min, idioms

We use

```
x += y
```

instead of

```
x = x + y
```

And similarly for `*,/,-` and other operators. Well, what about

```
x min= y
```

instead of

```
x = std::min(x, y)
```

? Is there a commonly-used idiom for this command, not requiring the (impossible) extension of the language with another operator?

Comment: Yes.  `x min= y` is commonly referred to as a *syntax error*. :)

Comment: You can't invent new operators in C++ like that, so the idiom is what you've written: `x = std::min(x, y)`.

Comment: There isn't anything like that in c++ or any means to define it.

Comment: `+=` is not two operators. It is one operator introduced in the language for short notation, because it's so commonly used operation. Introducing an operator for all possible functions seems unfeasible.

Comment: @Moo-Juice Unless `min` is a macro.  (But it better not be, because if it is, we can't include any standard headers.)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's certainly not idiomatic, but you might be able to use something called **named operators** (see these Q&As [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15090751/819272) and [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/23179/23476), developed by @Yakk and @KonradRudolph), and write

```
x <min>= y;
```

which is made possible by overloading `operator<` and `operator>`, combined with a clever wrapped `named_operator`. The full code is given by the link above, but uses code like

```
template <typename T1, typename T2, typename F>
inline auto operator >(named_operator_lhs<T1, F> const& lhs, T2 const& rhs)
    -> decltype(lhs.f(std::declval<T1>(), std::declval<T2>()))
{
    return lhs.f(lhs.value, rhs);
}
```

Using `std::min` as template argument for the template parameter `F`, would update the lhs of the expression with the min of the lhs and rhs.

Comment: ... this is madness... (+1 though, really interesting)

Comment: +1 for demonstrating the arcane powers unleashed by template magic

Comment: OMG OMG OMG OMG I hate C++, tralalalaaaa... (+1)

Comment: @Xaqq sorry, I wish I had invented this, but I didn't. Added the names of Yakk and Konrad Rudolph to it.

Answer (score 2):

You can't extend the language in this way.  The closest you can
come is something like:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
T&
mineq( T& lhs, U rhs )
{
    if ( rhs < lhs ) {
        lhs = rhs;
    }
    return lhs;
}
```

This would allow writing:

```
mineq( x, y );
```

I question whether it's worth the bother, however.

Answer (score 1):

NO. There is no such thing, you'll have to do with `std::min(x,y);`

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to create new custom operators.

You have a few available solutions though:

```
llama_min_age = std::min(x, y);
llama_min_age = (x < y ? x : y);
```

Or even a macro if you want to:

```
#define MIN(x, y) ((x) < (y) ? (x) : (y))
```

About the macro: it can lead to vicious bug, so I would prefer to use one of the first two solutions.

Comment: I wanted an idiom for the conditional assignment, not for the maximum values.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write this kind of sentences, they are reserved for the built-in syntaxt

Answer (score 0):

The options you have:

```
x = std::min(x,y)
```

or

```
x = y < x ? y : x;
```

or

```
if (y < x) x = y;
```

Answer (score 0):

C++ has a limited set of [operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword) and [keywords](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B).

What you are trying to do is outside the C++ specification and is not possible.

You can do the comparison and assignment with this one-liner if you want:

`x = (x < y) ? x : y;`

Comment: Only six? I count eight.

Comment: @James `x = (x SPACE1 < SPACE2 y) SPACE3 ? SPACE4 x SPACE5 : SPACE6 y;`

Comment: @H2CO3 this is so trivial an example that if you know the syntax you'll know what it does immediately. If it was used somewhere else, in a long line of code, complex call, I'd understand your comments. But in this case... Your're more pedantic than `gcc -pedantic`. But OK, I'll edit the post, just for the two of you.

Comment: @James and yes, I think that 6 spaces is better than 8 in this case.

Comment: @Dariusz Thanks. It's not that it's not obvious - of course I grasp what it means. It's just that it really is more readable with spaces. And yeah, I'm usually more pedantic than `cc -pedantic` :)

Comment: @H2CO3 Ah well, you say `tomato`, I say `potato`.  ;)  Personally, I put spaces inside braces/parentheses/brackets, except when there are multiple together in which case I collapse them (except for the inner pair if they're empty). For example, `fn( fn2( param, fn3() ))`.

Comment: @James Yeah, I know, and it's ugly :) I follow the Linux Kernel coding style - the best style I know of.

Comment: @H2CO3 The Linux Kernel style is very similar to what I have to use at work now. Suffice to say I have not had to work with such unreadable code in a very long time. In many respects it reminds me of how I used to program when I was first learning C over 20 years ago. But anyway, I think we're sufficiently off topic now.  :)