# Assignment operator with an explicit template in C++

Tags: c++, templates, operator-keyword

I'd like to define multiple ways of assignment operators. Minimal example code.

```
enum class AssignType {
    DeepCopy,
    SharedCopy
};

struct Container
{
    const char* x;
    template<AssignType >
    Container& operator=(const Container& other) {
        x = other.x; return *this;
    }
    // ...some specialisations of operator=() could be made
};

int main()
{
    Container i1, i2;
    i2.operator=<AssignType::DeepCopy>(i1);
    i2 =<AssignType::DeepCopy> i1; // line 20
    return 0;
}
```

The g++'s parser gives me an error for line 20. Is there any way to use operators in the "short" form (like in line 20) with explicit templates? C++11 allowed.

Comment: `const char* x; x = other.x;` is not a deep copy. however, how do you decide when it is a deep/shallow copy? is Container able to hold both at the same time?

Comment: No, there's no way to do this with that notation.  You can write non-operator/named function template..., but of course that won't support the `=<DEEPCOPY>` notation.  You could easily use two wrapper classes instead of an enum to support a notation like `i2 = DeepCopy(i1)`.

Comment: @itwasntpete: that's kind of the point - there's a postulated shallow copy default, and implied deep copy specialisation.

Comment: Fixed. It should not have a name, anyways...

Comment: all caps is conventionally reserved for macros.

Comment: There are [Yakk](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1774667/yakk)'s named operators, e.g. `i2 <DeepCopy>= i1;` (probably `i2 =<DeepCopy> i1` works with the same trick), follow [this answer and the links in the comments](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15090751/420683)

Comment: It won't work with the same trick.

Comment: @DeadMG m( Of course. I was too tired and read `<=` instead of `=<`. So `i2 <=DeepCopy> i1;` was possible, but ugly.