# Why doesn't my tag type survive perfect forwarding?

Tags: c++, templates

I want to select a specifc class implementation based on the presence of a tag type in the parameter type. This worked OK without the perfect fowarding of the argumnet (which I need for other reasons, see [How to store a reference when it is an lvalue, store a copy when it is an rvalue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28743557/how-to-store-a-reference-when-it-is-an-lvalue-store-a-copy-when-it-is-an-rvalue?noredirect=1#comment45773650_28743557)), but now it fails. Why, and how can I repair it?

```
#include <utility>

template< typename T > 
struct always_false : std::false_type {};

struct gpio { typedef void is_gpio; };

template <int N >
struct lpc_gpio : public gpio {};

template< typename T, typename dummy = void>
struct invert_impl {
   static_assert( always_false< T >::value, "cannot invert this type" );  
};

template< typename T >
struct invert_impl< T, typename T::is_gpio > : public gpio {};

template< typename P >
invert_impl< P > invert( P && pin ){
    return invert_impl< P >( pin );
}

int main(){
   auto pin4 = lpc_gpio< 4 >{};
   // the next line rpoduces the static_assert
   auto led = invert( pin4 );
}
```

My hunch was that I should remove the reference, typename remove_reference_t< P >::is_gpio (or rather, the 11 equivalent), but that does not work:

```
  #include <utility>
  #include <type_traits>

  template< typename T > 
  struct always_false : std::false_type {};

  struct gpio { typedef void is_gpio; };

  template <int N >
  struct lpc_gpio : public gpio { };

  template< typename T, typename dummy = void>
  struct invert_impl {
     static_assert( always_false< T >::value, "cannot invert this type" );  
  };

  template< typename T >
  struct invert_impl< T, typename std::remove_reference< T >::type::is_gpio > : public gpio {};

  template< typename P >
  invert_impl< P > invert( P && pin ){
      return invert_impl< P >( pin ); // line 22
  }

  int main(){
     auto pin4 = lpc_gpio< 4 >{};
     // the next line rpoduces the static_assert
     auto led = invert( pin4 ); // line 28
     (void)led;
  }
```

gives

```
main.cpp: In instantiation of 'invert_impl<P> invert(P&&) [with P = lpc_gpio<4>&]':
main.cpp:28:34:   required from here
main.cpp:22:40: error: no matching function for call to 'invert_impl<lpc_gpio<4>&, void>::invert_impl(lpc_gpio<4>&)'
       return invert_impl< P >( pin );
```

Comment: Can you provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: "My hunch was that I should remove the reference, `typename remove_reference_t< P >::is_gpio`, but that does not work." -- It should work, that's exactly what you should do, and when I test it, it does work. (Aside from the missing constructor from your other question, anyway.) Are you sure you didn't accidentally try `typename std::remove_reference<P>::is_gpio` (forgetting the `_t`)?

Comment: @hvd (you again!) I added the version with std::remove_reference<T>::type

Comment: Yup. :) Yeah, that error you're getting is just because you didn't include a constructor in your `invert_impl` in this question, so `invert_impl` just has a default constructor, copy constructor and move constructor, but nothing taking `T`.

Comment: :( :( :( (and 6 more to go)