# Operator overloading + operator in C++. How to overload objecttypeA+ObjectypeA = Objectype B?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have two classes. Class OnePoint, and Class Line.

A OnePoint consists of a point, two coordinates.

A Class Line consists of two points, two OnePoint objects.

How can I add two OnePoints so that it becomes a line with operator overloading?

```
OnePoint a(3.0, 3.0); 
OnePoint b(1.0, 1.0); 

Line d; 

d = a+b; 

cout << d;
```

becomes `{(3.0,3.0),(1.0,1.0)}`.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class OnePoint {
private:
    double xvalue;
    double yvalue;

public:
    OnePoint(double x = 0.0, double y = 0.0) {
        xvalue = x;
        yvalue = y;

    }

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& printh, OnePoint& cPoint) {
        printh << "(" << cPoint.xvalue << ',' << cPoint.yvalue << ")";
        return printh;

    }

    void Plus(OnePoint a) {
        xvalue = xvalue + a.xvalue;
        yvalue = yvalue + a.yvalue;
    }

    void Minus(OnePoint b) {

        xvalue = xvalue + b.xvalue;
        yvalue = yvalue + b.yvalue;

    }

    OnePoint Plustwo(OnePoint a) {
        return (xvalue + a.xvalue, yvalue - a.yvalue);

    }

    void Change(double a, double b) {
        xvalue += a;
        yvalue += b;
    }

    void Print(OnePoint b) {

        cout << xvalue << "," << yvalue << endl;

    }

    /*OnePoint operator-(OnePoint a) {
        OnePoint temp;
        temp.xvalue = xvalue + a.xvalue;
        temp.yvalue = yvalue + a.yvalue;

        return temp;

    }


    friend OnePoint operator+(OnePoint a, OnePoint b) {
        OnePoint temp;
        temp.xvalue = a.xvalue + b.xvalue;
        temp.yvalue = a.yvalue + b.yvalue;

        return temp;

    }*/


};



class Line {
private: 
    OnePoint onevalue; 
    OnePoint twovalue; 
public: 
    Line(OnePoint a, OnePoint b) {
        onevalue = a; 
        twovalue = b; 

    }

    /*OnePoint getonevalue() {
        return onevalue; 
    }

    OnePoint gettwovalue() {

        return twovalue; 
    }*/

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& print, Line& cLine){
        print << "{"<< cLine.onevalue << ',' << cLine.twovalue << "}"; 
        return print; 
    }

    friend Line operator+(OnePoint a, OnePoint b) {
        Line temp;                                    // I have been trying 
        temp(a, b);                           //something here without luck

        return temp;
    }

};



-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
int main(){

    OnePoint a(3.0, 3.0); 
    OnePoint b(1.0, 1.0);  

    Line d(a, b); 



    cout << a << endl;

    cout << d << endl; 

    }
```

Comment: Don't you mean `Line temp(a, b);`? Or plain `return Line(a, b);`.

Comment: Oh and in the future, when you have a problem please tell us *what* problem you have. Just saying e.g. `I have tried this and it doesn't work" is not very helpful. If you get build errors, then tell us the errors. If you get runtime errors, tell us about that too, and if possible try to pinpoint the crash in a debugger. If you get unexpected output, include the actual and the expected output, together with the input which caused the unexpected output.

Comment: Do you really want to do this? Speaking mathematically, adding two points does not give you a line, it gives you another point. It's usually best to stick to the well-defined mathematical meaning when overloading operators.

Comment: To be clear, *subtracting* two points gives you a (mathematical, not `std`) *vector*.

Comment: @Andrew Mathematically speaking, adding two points is nonsense.

Comment: `Line d(a, b)` would be a _lot_ clearer for others reading your code.

Comment: @molbdnilo Fair enough. I wasn't really debating the technicalities, more pointing out that `operator+` probably isn't the right thing to express the construction of a line.

Answer (score 2):

You can rewrite (in C++11) your `operator +` like

```
Line operator+(const OnePoint& lhs, const OnePoint& rhs)
{
    return {lhs, rhs};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do - without changing anything - is

```
OnePoint a(3.0, 3.0);
OnePoint b(1.0, 1.0); 
Line d(a,b);
```

If you really want to do

```
d = a + b;
```

then you need to supply an `operator+()` that accepts two arguments of type `OnePoint`, and returns a `Line`.   The alternatives are doing it as a member of `OnePoint`

```
 // definition of Line here

class OnePoint
{
    public:
        Line operator+(const OnePoint &) const;

         //  other member functions, etc 
};

Line OnePoint::operator+(const OnePoint &rhs) const
{
     Line retval(*this, rhs);
     return retval;
}
```

or as a non-member

```
 // definitions of Line and OnePoint here

 Line operator+(const OnePoint &lhs, const OnePoint &rhs);   // declaration, not definition

 Line operator+(const OnePoint &lhs, const OnePoint &rhs)
 {
      Line retval(lhs, rhs);
      return retval;
 }
```

Obviously, in both cases above, I have assumed that the `operator+()`s have access as needed (e.g. to `Line`' constructor).

Note that, mathematically, what you are doing is backward.   Points are not added using `a+b` syntax to get a line - a line is represented using a pair of points, not a summation.   Instead, vectors are added to points to produce other points.

Comment: I really, really want to write d = a+b; They should both have, I think. Whenever I write Line p; for example I get no default constructor exists for this class. At the same time I can write OnePoint p; and I get no error.

Comment: Oh, I see what's wrong, I have to give it default paramameters I think.

Comment: @DavidLund it's because OnePoint has a default constructor (calling it with the defaulted arguments), but Line has no default constructor because you defined a non-default constructor.

Comment: Yes, I figured it out :p Thanks btw. I'm just happy nobody said this doesn't work. That would be the biggest horror.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is very trivial. Your Line class constructor is multiple parameter constructor and you need to construct `Line` object using two argument of `OnePoint` type.

I have corrected you code and you will get idea of how to construct object of class if constructor require one or more parameter.

```
friend Line operator+(OnePoint a, OnePoint b) {
            Line temp(a,b);                                    // Changed here
            return temp;
        }
```

you can also go through this [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/) to learn basics about object construction

Answer (score 0):

Do not override `+` to do that.  It is exceedingly unexpected.

If you really need a clean syntax, use a named operator.

Here is a 12 line [named operator library](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15090751/1774667):

```
namespace named_operator {
  template<class D>struct make_operator{make_operator(){}};

  template<class T, char, class O> struct half_apply { T&& lhs; };

  template<class Lhs, class Op>
  half_apply<Lhs, '*', Op> operator*( Lhs&& lhs, make_operator<Op> ) {
    return {std::forward<Lhs>(lhs)};
  }

  template<class Lhs, class Op, class Rhs>
  auto operator*( half_apply<Lhs, '*', Op>&& lhs, Rhs&& rhs )
  -> decltype( invoke( std::forward<Lhs>(lhs.lhs), Op{}, std::forward<Rhs>(rhs) ) )
  {
    return invoke( std::forward<Lhs>(lhs.lhs), Op{}, std::forward<Rhs>(rhs) );
  }
}
```

then we define an actual named operator using the above library as follows:

```
struct line_to_tag {}; // tag type
static const named_operator::make_operator<line_to_tag> line_to; // name of operator

// action from operator:
Line invoke( OnePoint lhs, line_to_tag, OnePoint rhs ) {
  return Line(lhs, rhs);
}
```

and now this works:

```
Point a, b;
Line l = a *lineto* b;
```

which I think is far more clear than `a+b`.  (and yes, the named operator library is a bit confusing, but the code *at point of use* is very clear).

Comment: I am very thankful for your input, but I am destined to use the + sign even though it isn't very intuitive.

Comment: @DavidLund How about `a ->* b`?

Comment: If you can post your solution I can see. It might get too complicated for me. I managed to do Line d =a+b now, so I have kind of done what I wanted :)