# Multiplying a valarray of complex numbers by a scalar

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, complex-numbers, valarray

`valarray<double>` can be multiplied by a scalar. However, I get an error when I want to multiply by a scalar for a `valarray<complex<double>>`. I'm wondering if there's a way to do it in a pretty manner. Here's a reproduction of the problem:

```
valarray<complex<double>> v1{ { complex<double>{1,0}, complex<double>{2,0}, complex<double>{3,0} } };
valarray<complex<double>> v2 = v1 * 2.0; // error
```

generates `Error C2784: 'std::complex<_Other> std::operator *(const std::complex<_Other> &,const std::complex<_Other> &)': could not deduce template argument for 'const std::complex<_Other> &' from 'std::vector<std::complex<double>,std::allocator<_Ty>>'`.

So I tried to build my own function to see if it can be done and the following works:

```
valarray<complex<double>> VAMult(const valarray<complex<double>> &v, double scalar)
{
    valarray<complex<double>> out(v.size());
    for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
    {
        out[i] = v[i] * scalar;
    }
    return out;
}

// makes the following code work:
valarray<complex<double>> v2 = VAMult(v1, 2.0);
```

But this implementation would make for really ugly code so I looked into valarray.h and found the * overload definition:

```
operator*(const _Ty& _Left,
        const valarray<_Ty>& _Right)
{   // return scalar * valarray
    _VALOP(_Ty, _Right.size(), _Left * _Right[_Idx]);
}

#define _VALOP(TYPE, LENGTH, RHS)   /* assign RHS(_Idx) to new valarray */ \
valarray<TYPE> _Ans(LENGTH); \
for (size_t _Idx = 0; _Idx < _Ans.size(); ++_Idx) \
    _Ans[_Idx] = RHS; \
return (_Ans)
```

My knowledge of templating is very limited but is it possible to extend this class? Here's my attempt:

```
valarray<complex<double>> valarray<complex<double>>::operator*(const double &scalar)
{
    return valarray<complex<double>>{};
}
```

resulting in `Error C2039 '*': is not a member of 'std::valarray<std::complex<double>>'`

Is there a way to make it so my first line of code `v1 * 2.0` works or some close compromise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to make it so my first line of code v1 * 2.0 works or
>   some close compromise?

Yes: multiply `v1` with a complex scalar.

The following code compile

```
#include <complex>
#include <valarray>

int main()
 {
   std::valarray<std::complex<double>> v1{ { {1,0}, {2,0}, {3,0} } };
   std::valarray<std::complex<double>> v2 = v1 * std::complex<double>{2.0};
 }
```

The problem is that `valarray` is a template class with an `operator*()` (and similar operators) that is defined only over the template type.

So a `std::valarray<double>` can be multiplied with a `double` scalar, a `std::valarray<std::complex<double>>` can be multiplied with a `std::complex<double>` scalar but a `std::valarray<std::complex<double>>` can't be multiplied with a `double` scalar.

Comment: I could have sworn I tried this but the second and third values were random. This is an acceptable compromise given my limited scope.

Answer (score 3):

Specializing `operator*` in this case is both illegal and won't get you what you want.

An overload could, but it is illegal to add overloads to `namespace std`.  (This may change in [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) or [c++23](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b23))

We can do:

```
valarray<complex<double>> v1{ { complex<double>{1,0}, complex<double>{2,0}, complex<double>{3,0} } };
valarray<complex<double>> v2 = v1 * complex<double>{2.0};
```

but I assume you knew that.

You could use [named operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15090209/does-boost-have-a-datatype-for-set-operations-that-is-simpler-than-the-stl/15090751#15090751) and get:

```
valarray<complex<double>> v2 = v1 *times* 2.0;
```

to work legally.

You could also write your own literal to-complex converter:

```
std::complex<double> operator"" _cplx( long double t ) {
  return {(double)std::move(t)};
}
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/874b78799156b1de).

But really, cast to `complex<double>`.