# Min/Max dyadic operators

Tags: c++

I have been dreaming for years about dyadic operators min and max similar to other arithmetic operators.

E.g.

```
int a, b, c;
cout << (a min b) max c;
```

As well as the corresponding assignment operators,

```
a min= b;
```

How can I lobby to obtain this in a future version ?

Possible notation could be `\/` and `/\`, but I have no strong requirement about this :-)

The question is not about set and ranges, but numerical types.

Comment: It's worth noting that GCC has/had these as an extension: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.2/gcc/Min-and-Max.html. In addition, you can get close to the first code with a named operator implementation. I want to say this was discussed on std-proposals as well, but I can't find it.

Comment: Easy to make as, say `a *min* b`, check Yakk answer in the link I provided

Comment: The question about how to encourage the standards committee to adopt it isn't really on-topic here, which is supposed to be about actual programming questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does boost have a datatype for set operations that is simpler than the STL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15090209/does-boost-have-a-datatype-for-set-operations-that-is-simpler-than-the-stl)

Comment: @Barmar: of course not, but I have no idea where to ask.

Comment: Catch-22: Asking where to ask would also be off-topic. :)

Comment: @chris: a step in the right direction, thanks. The assignments `>?=` and `<?=` would even be more useful.

Comment: Google WG21....

Comment: Proposal exists for letting you write *any* binary function as infix, that is, `a.min(b)` becomes equivalent to `min(a,b)` even though `min` is not a member of `decltype(a)`.   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Function_Call_Syntax

Comment: @rustyx: that's what I was looking for. You can enter this as an answer (though indeed not the right site for this topic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's the ISO [working group 21](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/) who decide what goes into the ISO C++ standard and what doesn't.

And here's [the process of submitting a proposal to WG21](https://isocpp.org/std/submit-a-proposal).

It begins with participating in the mailings of the working group and getting on the agenda of an upcoming meeting to discuss your idea. It's actually possible, but it takes *a lot* of effort.